# Avoid using eval() to call function by name with only dynamic string

Tags: javascript, node.js, dynamic, eval

I have this simple switch block:

```
function modifyServiceContractView(schema) {
     ...
}

function modifyContactView(schema) {
    ...
}


function addExtraInfoToSchema(defName, schema) {

  switch (defName) {

    case 'ServiceContractView':
      return modifyServiceContractView(schema);
      break;

    case 'ContactView':
      return modifyContactView(schema);
      break;

    default:
      return schema;

  }

}
```

instead of hardcoding a switch block, it would be nice to just have something like this instead:

```
function modifyServiceContractView(schema) {
    ...
}

function modifyContactView(schema) {
    ...
}


function addExtraInfoToSchema(defName, schema) {

    return eval('modify' + defName+ '(schema)');

}
```

is there a better way to do this without eval()?

hopefully my question is clear.

Comment: Yes, use an object literal to store your functions..  you can then do  func['modify' + defName](schema)

Comment: duh :) thanks I knew there was a way lulz

Comment: can you add it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Use an object whose keys are the names and values are the functions.

```
var modifyFuncs = {
    ServiceContractView: modifyServiceContractView,
    ContactView: modifyContactView
};

function addExtraInfoToSchema(defName, schema) {
    if (defName in modifyFuncs) {
        return modifyFuncs[defName](schema);
    } else {
        return schema;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could store your functions in an object then access them by name.

```js
var modify = {
  ServiceContractView: function(schema) {
    console.log('ServiceContract', schema);
  },
  ContactView: function(schema) {
    console.log('Contact', schema);
  }
};

function addExtraInfoToSchema(defName, schema) {
  return modify[defName](schema);
}

addExtraInfoToSchema('ServiceContractView', 1);
addExtraInfoToSchema('ContactView', 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the functions object properties:

```
return (f => f ? f(schema) : schema)({
    modifyServiceContractView,
    modifyContactView
}['modify' + defName]);
```

Comment: `window` doesn't exist in node. Besides, making them global (in node) is a bad decision and unnecessary.